# Poisson distribution normal approximation

Tags: statistics

6.4.18. An experimenter takes a sample of size 1 from
the Poisson probability model, pX (k) = e−λλk/k!, k =
0, 1, 2, . . . , and wishes to test
H0: λ=6
versus
H1:λ<6
by rejecting H0 if k ≤2.
(a) Calculate the probability of committing a Type I
error.

Can someone explain what is the best way to approach this problem thank you

Comment: The best way to approach this problem is to first check the definition of Type 1 error in your textbook and to try to locate in your specific setting every quantity involved in this definition. What is a problem in this suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

We make a Type I error if we wrongly reject the null hypothesis. So you need to calculate the probability that we get $0$ or $1$ or $2$ "successes" **given** that $\lambda=6$, that is, given that the null hypothesis holds.

You have a relevant formula. If $\lambda=6$, then the probability that $X=k$ is $e^{-6}\dfrac{6^k}{k!}$. You need to calculate $\Pr(X=0)+\Pr(X=1)+\Pr(X=2)$.  Approximations by the normal are not appropriate.